# How to hide the <apex:enhancedlist>

Tags: apex, javascript

I have side bar with a custom Html area component ,which consists of links, by clicking on the links corresponding  should show , but when i hide and show it displays in narrow line format , how to eliminate this error[image]

but after clicking on refresh button in it shows up in regular display

APEX CODE:

```
  <div class="conntents">
  <apex:enhancedlist type="Account" height="300" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" />
  </div>

   <div class="conntents">
 <apex:enhancedlist type="Create_Account__c" height="300" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" />
 </div>

    <div class="conntents">
<apex:enhancedlist type="Admin__c" height="300" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" />
 </div>
```

Javascript :

```
function clicker(var1)
{
    var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("conntents");
    for(var i=0; i<contents.length; i++)
    {
        if(var1 == i)
        {
        document.getElementsByClassName("conntents")[var1].style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
        document.getElementsByClassName("conntents")[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: i have added the code

Answer (score 1):

There is a error in you javascript. You are surely getting error in script. Because you are setting `inline` style to element which is not defined.

use your code like this:

```
<div class="conntents" style="display:none">
  <apex:enhancedlist type="Account" height="300" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" />
  </div>

   <div class="conntents" style="display:none">
 <apex:enhancedlist type="Create_Account__c" height="300" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" />
 </div>

    <div class="conntents" style="display:none">
<apex:enhancedlist type="Admin__c" height="300" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" />
 </div>
```

then:

```
function clicker(var1) {
    var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("conntents");
    for(var i=0; i<contents.length; i++) {
        if(var1 == i) {
           contents[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
           contents[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```